# How to include iText Library with licensed in android app?

Tags: itext

If i have license from itext, then what are the steps to include iText jar file in my android application?
Do i need to just download the jar and add into my project?
Or do i need to do something else?

Comment: If you plan to purchase a license for iText, I am sure they will explain the license term to you. There are probably different licenses available for different types of projects (Android app vs Saas vs in-house app etc).

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this is a bit out of scope for StackOverflow and the instructions should have been given to you when you received your license key, but here's how to add the key:

The jar is added to the classpath like any other library. You'll also need to download and add the licensekey jar to the classpath, which can be found here: http://itextsupport.com/download/licensekey.html

You'll then need to load your license key before using any other iText operation by calling

```
LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile("path/to/itextkey.xml")
```